# Как сделать связи один ко многим используя nestjs typeorm graphql psql?

Tags: nestjs, graphql

Не могу разобраться как сделать так, чтобы пользователю добавлялись избранные им страны. Связью один ко многим.
Сначала код потом схема.
Смотрю на полученную схему там всё как надо.

```
    input UpdateUserInput {
      id: ID!
      login: String
      password: String
    }
    
    type UserEntity {
      countries: [CountryEntity!]
      createdAt: DateTime!
      id: ID!
      login: String!
      password: String!
      updateAt: DateTime!
    }
input CreateUserInput {
  login: String!
  password: String!
}
type CountryEntity {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  id: ID!
  nameCountry: String!
  updateAt: DateTime!
  user: UserEntity!
}

input CreateCountryInput {
  nameCountry: String!
}
```

Какой писал код сущность пользователя

```
@OneToMany(() => CountryEntity, (country) => country.user, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @Field(() => [CountryEntity], { nullable: true })
  countries: CountryEntity[];
```

Какой писал код сущность страна

```
 @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.countries, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @Field(() => UserEntity)
  user: UserEntity;
```

А что теперь то нужно ? Как задавать им значения так далее